# Apache Flink：keyby and window operator

Tags: apache-flink, apache-storm, flink-streaming

I want to know some mechanisms related to keyedstream.
The code is as follows：

```
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts =
            // split up the lines in pairs (2-tuples) containing: (word,1)
            text.flatMap(new Tokenizer())
            // group by the tuple field "0" and sum up tuple field "1"
                    .keyBy(0)
                    .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(3)))
```

If I want to implement window wordcount.

Q1:Is there only one key in each window or multiple keys?

Q2:For the functions in the window, I only use simple sum++ or need to handle the sum of multiple keys through the hashmap in the window like Apache Storm.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if there are actually multiple keys per window, each call to your `process`/`reduce`/`sum`/`aggregate` function is made with elements with the same key.

In your example you can just use `sum` and Flink will take care of everything:

```
text.flatMap(new Tokenizer())
      .keyBy(0)
      .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(3)))
      .sum(X)
```

If you chose to go with a `reduce` instead...

```
text.flatMap(new Tokenizer())
      .keyBy(0)
      .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(3)))
      .reduce(new ReduceFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>>(){
            @Override
            public Tuple2<String, Integer> reduce(final Tuple2<String, Integer> first, final Tuple2<String, Integer> second) {
                  (... do something with the guarantee that first[0] == second[0] (same key) ...)
            }
      });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the flink documentation, I see the following example.It doesn't do anything to guarantee the same key as you said.`DataStream<Tuple2<String, Long>> input = ...;

input
    .keyBy(<key selector>)
    .window(<window assigner>)
    .reduce(new ReduceFunction<Tuple2<String, Long>> {
      public Tuple2<String, Long> reduce(Tuple2<String, Long> v1, Tuple2<String, Long> v2) {
        return new Tuple2<>(v1.f0, v1.f1 + v2.f1);
      }
    });`

Comment: You mean that Frink has a guarantee inside, or I need to implement the logic guarantee myself. I seem to have misunderstood what you mean. :)

Comment: @ChengJiang Flink provides that guarantee internally, you don't have to implement anything.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thanks for the answer. :)